# How to rotate this 180 degrees?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

```
 o            o 
  '          '  
   '        '   
    :-'""'-:    
 .-'  ____  '-. 
( (  (_()_)  ) )
 '-.   ^^  .-'  
    '._==_.'    
    ___)(___
```

This image is in a text file. I was able to load this into a 2-d array but can't seem to rotate it 180 degrees. I've been using this function to try and rotate it.

```
void rotateImage(char alien[ROWS][COLS]){

    char temp; 

    for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c < COLS; c++){
            temp = alien[r][c];
            alien[r][c] = alien[r][COLS-1-c];
            alien[r][COLS-1-c] = temp;
            printf("%c", alien[r][COLS-1-c]);
        }
    
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not to sure how to get started with it." You need to ask a more specific question. Whar is it you don't know? How define a 2D char array? How to open a text file? How to read characters from a text file? What exactly is stopping you from solving the problem?

Comment: Break the task into smaller tasks that you can solve. For instance... Step 1) Write a program that opens a file and then closes the file. Step 2) Extend the program so it reads all characters in the file and prints them. Step 3) Extend the program so it saves the characters in a 2D array. And so on...

Comment: By "flip", presumably you mean "rotate"?  Or, if you mean "reflect", then how should the 180 degree angle be applied to the reflection?  Does that specify the axis?  Show the expected output, and also post the code you've written.  Note that, as ascii characters, just moving the characters probably won't produce the image you want.  You will also need to "rotate" (or "reflect") the characters, which will not always be possible.

Comment: How do you expect to look your text after flipping? You may reverse or rotatee the characters, but `^` will not become `v` automatically. Also characters like `'` or `"` will not look the same if rotated.

Comment: As I also commented on your duplicate question: You should only swap things above the diagonal of the array; currently you're swapping, and once you're past the diagonal, you're swapping them back.